# How to select on CSV files by R sqldf/data.table/dplyr?

Tags: csv, r, sql

I know the thread [How can I inner join two csv files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187372/how-can-i-inner-join-two-csv-files-in-r) which has a merge option, which I do not want. 
I have two data CSV files. I am thinking how to query like them like SQL with R. 
Two CSV files where primary key is `data_id`. 
`data.csv` where OK to have IDs not found in `log.csv` (etc `4`)

```
data_id, event_value
1, 777
1, 666
2, 111
4, 123 
3, 324
1, 245
```

`log.csv` where no duplicates in `ID` column but duplicates can be in `name`

```
data_id, name
1, leo
2, leopold
3, lorem
```

Pseudocode by partial PostgreSQL syntax

1. Let `data_id=1`
2. Show `name` and `event_value` from `data.csv` and `log.csv`, respectively

Pseudocode like partial PostgreSQL select

```
SELECT name, event_value 
    FROM data, log
    WHERE data_id=1;
```

Expected output

```
leo, 777
leo, 666 
leo, 245
```

### R approach

```
file1 <- read.table("file1.csv", col.names=c("data_id", "event_value"))
file2 <- read.table("file2.csv", col.names=c("data_id", "name"))

# TODO here something like the SQL query 
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/1307824/54964
```

Possible approaches where I think `sqldf` can be sufficient here

1. `sqldf`
2. `data.table`
3. `dplyr`

PostgreSQL Schema pseudocode to show what I am trying to do with CSV files

```
CREATE TABLE data (
        data_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        event_value INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE log (
        data_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        name INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

R: 3.3.3
OS: Debian 8.7
Related: PostgreSQL approach in the relevant thread [How to SELECT with two CSV files/… on PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/173532/69807)

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187372/how-can-i-inner-join-two-csv-files-in-r

Comment: The SQL here seems tangential and requires people to be familiar with both platforms to understand what you're asking. Your expected result looks like you want to merge and find keys with duplicates, or maybe merge and display just the results for a particular key, but the SQL doesn't seem to support either interpretation.

Comment: I still have no idea what you actually want; but my suspicion is that it's something really basic, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463562/how-do-you-match-each-value-of-a-vector-with-a-key-value-dictionary

Comment: @tripleee Absolutely no. Please, see *Possible approaches* section where I think `sqldf` is most closest here, which I am thinking too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `sqldf` approach.

One approach which shows a caveat with `join` approach - you cannot use `WHERE data_id` on both tables if you join by `data_id`. 
Code 1

```
file1 <- read.table("data.csv", col.names=c("data_id", "event_value"))
file2 <- read.table("log.csv", col.names=c("data_id", "name"))

library("sqldf")
df3 <- sqldf("SELECT event_value, name
   FROM file1
   LEFT JOIN file2 USING(data_id)")

df3
```

Output wrong because `data_id = 1` should be active too

```
Loading required package: gsubfn
Loading required package: proto
Loading required package: RSQLite
Loading required package: tcltk
Warning message:
Quoted identifiers should have class SQL, use DBI::SQL() if the caller performs the quoting. 
  event_value    name
1 event_value    name
2         777     leo
3         666     leo
4         111 leopold
5         123    <NA>
6         324   lorem
7         245     leo
```

### Code 2

Code

```
df3 <- sqldf("SELECT event_value, name
   FROM file1
   LEFT JOIN file2 USING(data_id)
   WHERE data_id = 1")
```

Output blank because `join` applied already

```
[1] event_value name       
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

### Code 3

Do `WHERE` earlier

```
df3 <- sqldf("SELECT event_value, name
   FROM file1
   WHERE data_id = 1
   LEFT JOIN file2 USING(data_id)")
```

Output error because two tables are of different size so `WHERE` should be applied on both tables

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  near "LEFT": syntax error
Calls: sqldf ... initialize -> initialize -> rsqlite_send_query -> .Call
In addition: Warning message:
Quoted identifiers should have class SQL, use DBI::SQL() if the caller performs the quoting. 
Execution halted
```

### Code 4

Using two `SELECT`s with `JOIN`

```
df3 <- sqldf("SELECT event_value, name
   FROM file1
   WHERE data_id = 1
   LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT data_id, name
       FROM file2
       WHERE data_id = 1)
   USING(data_id)")
```

Output error

```
Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  near "LEFT": syntax error
Calls: sqldf ... initialize -> initialize -> rsqlite_send_query -> .Call
In addition: Warning message:
Quoted identifiers should have class SQL, use DBI::SQL() if the caller performs the quoting. 
Execution halted
```

Maybe, a syntax error with the second `SELECT` and its attachment to `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

R has a number of packages that come with the SQL level of convenience. The most convenient packages are

- dplyr (modern, usually 10-100 times speed against the base functions) with SQL-inspired commands such as group-by and different joins
- SparkR (if you need Spark support, not apparently here but this come with nice SQL-convenient commands) with SQL-inspired commands such as group-by and different joins
- `data-table` provides more efficient functions than the base functions such as replace `read.csv` with `fread`.
- The SQLDF is very unreliable and inefficient, yes you will get fatal error with the precedence error like above failing Rstudio.

where the packages won't teach you learn and debug SQL: in order to learn proper SQL, SQLDF is cerntainly not the most convenient tool for this. SQL Server Management Studio, Windows, may be easier to use for example with Azure Basic SQL DB, 5EUR/month or free tier [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) or some other DB -- or set up db yourself

- source postgres database with `src_postgres()` command, more about database commands in R [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html)

The below provides you demos, showing the proper SQL and fixing the bugs occurring in your Code cases. I also show the SQL convenience commands. It is good to learn SQL properly first so you know what to look for in the R packages.

### **DEMOS**

---

Code 4 is failing because of wrong precedence. The where-clause and the USING must be after the join.

> ```
> > file1 <- read.csv("test1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
> > file2 <- read.csv("test2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
>
> > sqldf("SELECT event_value, name
> +       FROM file1
> +       LEFT JOIN 
> +       (SELECT data_id, name
> +       FROM file2
> +       WHERE data_id = 1)
> +       USING(data_id)
> +       WHERE data_id = 1")
>   event_value name
> 1         777  leo
> 2         666  leo
> 3         245  leo
> ```

Other ways contain

*Proper LEFT-JOIN approach*

> ```
> > df3 <- sqldf("SELECT event_value, name
> +              FROM file1 a
> +              LEFT JOIN file2 b ON a.data_id=b.data_id")
> > 
> > df3
>   event_value    name
> 1         777     leo
> 2         666     leo
> 3         111 leopold
> 4         123    <NA>
> 5         324   lorem
> 6         245     leo
> > df3 <- sqldf("SELECT a.event_value, b.name
> +    FROM file1 a
> +              LEFT JOIN file2 b ON a.data_id=b.data_id
> +              WHERE a.data_id = 1")
> > df3
>   event_value name
> 1         777  leo
> 2         666  leo
> 3         245  leo
> ```

*Merging the tables with where condition*

> ```
> > df4 <- sqldf("SELECT a.event_value, b.name
> +    FROM file1 a, file2 b
> +              WHERE a.data_id = 1
> +              AND a.data_id=b.data_id")
> > 
> > df4
>   event_value name
> 1         777  leo
> 2         666  leo
> 3         245  leo
> ```

*SQL subqueries approach*

> ```
> > df5 <- sqldf("SELECT a.event_value, b.name
> +    FROM 
> +              (SELECT data_id, event_value FROM file1) a,
> +              (SELECT data_id, name FROM file2) b
> +              WHERE a.data_id = 1
> +              AND a.data_id=b.data_id")
> > df5
>   a.event_value b.name
> 1           777    leo
> 2           666    leo
> 3           245    leo
> ```

### **WHAT ARE SQL-CONVENIENT WAYS TO USE R?**

---

**[dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf)**

- SQL-style joins

  > [image]
- build_sql convenience function to execute SQL-style commands

  > [image]
- Case-when function is inspired by SQL-CASE-WHEN
- Coalesce function is inpsired by SQL-COALESCE
- translate_sql helps to convert R functions to SQL (more cases [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html))

  > ```
  > # Many functions have slightly different names
  > translate_sql(x == 1 && (y < 2 || z > 3))
  > #> <SQL> "x" = 1.0 AND ("y" < 2.0 OR "z" > 3.0)
  > translate_sql(x ^ 2 < 10)
  > #> <SQL> POWER("x", 2.0) < 10.0
  > translate_sql(x %% 2 == 10)
  > #> <SQL> "x" % 2.0 = 10.0
  > ```
- SQLLite and dplyr:  install the sqlite package and try the NYC dataset with dplyr, more [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html)

**SparkR package**

- comes with SQL-style joins (inner joins, left-joins, etc) and group-by. More [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/R/).

  > [image]

Comment: Assume you have 20 columns and 6, respectively in the tables. Which method would you use to join such tables and then do the request?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 because I have SQL Server (running on Windows server) available, I would use it and MMSM (Micsoft SQL Management Studio, free). If not, I would try try to find replacement for it. For very small data amount 6-20 cols (still little), I would try R and SQLDF with `SELECT TOP 100 Col1, col2,... FROM TABLE1` directive with `TOP100` (so not hanging up even with big amount of data) and/or dplyr if too slow. If I had no computer what-so-ever available (only chromebook or tablet or phone), I would do everything from Azure-SQL GUI: you can run SQL commands through the webinterface.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 [Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=785562) has alternatives and [DbVis](http://www.dbvis.com/features/feature-list/) looks promising, working in OSX/Linux/W. The free edition looks fine, driver to PostegreSQL but no scheduling. This looks similar to MMSM and you need to get the db set up first somewhere like your comp or Azure SQL.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Moved the DbVis point [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968956/which-db-driver-to-use-dbvisualiser-with-azure-sql) when you have no Windows os available. There may be other alternatives to MMSM.

Answer (score 0):

I make extensive use of the *Perl* language module **Text::CSV_XS** for heavy duty, ad-hoc manipulation of CSV files.  Using this module I've built four small basic *Perl* programs to use as building blocks for whatever I want to do.

1. Filter - Filter inputFile filterFile field
2. Reject - Reject inputFile filterFile field
3. Stripper - Stripper inputFile field [field2 field3…]
4. Swap - Swap inputFile swapFile matchField outfield

The filterFile has a regEx pattern on each line. Anything matching one of these patterns is matched for the purposes of acceptance or rejection.  The assorted "field"s are column header names.

So in your example I just put "1" in filterFile and go:

```
perl Filter.pm data.csv filter.txt data_id >One.csv
perl Stripper.pm One.csv data_id event_value >Two.csv
perl Swap.pm Two.csv log.csv data_id name >Three.csv
```

If we also wanted Leopold's events filter.txt would have two lines with eponymous contents:

```
1
2
```

I have assorted mutant versions of all four building block routines that do things like take input from STDIN or or post output to a specific URL.

If you wanted to do it directly with a special-purpose routine that would be fairly easy.  **Text::CSV_XS** easily pulls CSV file rows into hashes and then you can do what you like with them.

First though, if your files are huge you should use the **DB_File** module to specify that your hash should be stored on disk as a database.  Otherwise you can fill up memory and grind to a halt.

```
use DB_File;

my %theHash;
unlink '/tmp/translation.db';
sleep 2;
tie ( %theHash, 'DB_File', '/tmp/translation.db' )
    or die "Can't open /tmp/translation.db\n";
```

Then create CSV objects

```
map{ $_ = Text::CSV_XS->new( { allow_whitespace => 1,
        eol =>"\015\012",
        always_quote => 1, binary => 1 })}
   ( $data_csv, $log_csv, $output_csv );
```

Note that I'm using DOS EOL characters.

Then pull in the input header rows to set up the column names

```
@cols = @{$data_csv->getline( $data_fh )};
$data_csv->column_names( @cols );
@cols = @{$log_csv->getline( $log_fh )};
$log_csv->column_names( @cols );
```

where you've opened the files on the file handles $data_fh and $log_fh.

Decide what your output columns will be and write out a column header row

```
@output_cols = ( 'name', 'event_value' );
$output_csv->combine( @output_cols );
$latest_row = $output_csv->string();
print $output_fh, $latest_row;
```

Then make up a data_id to name hash.

```
while ( $log_csv_row = $log_csv->getline_hr( $log_fh ) ){
    $theHash{ $log_csv_row->{data_id} } = $log_csv_row->{name};
}
```

Then, as in your example, cycle through data.csv to get all of the '1's.

```
$outputHash{name} = $theHash{1};

while ( $data_csv_row = $data_csv->getline_hr( $data_fh ) ){

    next unless $data_csv_row->{data_id} == 1;

    $outputHash{data_id} = $data_csv_row->{data_id};
    $output_csv->combine( map { $outputHash{$_} } @output_cols );
    $latest_row = $output_csv->string();
    print $output_fh "$latest_row";
}
```

This example code is the basis for all of the utility routines listed above where the hardcoded '1' is replaced with assorted arguments or arrays of arguments that are put in hashes.

Comment: Can you give some examples with the pseudocode provided in the body? I feel the answer now a stub.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.  Do you mean examples of the utility routines I mention above in data pipelines or do you mean code using the 'TEXT::CSV_XS' module such as these utility routines?  The answer was just intended to be a stub since you said you just wanted possible approaches but I can expand on it if you like.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to get it more expanded with the examples about the utility routines and/or `TEXT::CSV_XS` module, for the pseudocode in the body. .